# problem while extracting file from tar

Tags: linux, tar

I have a tar.gz file. I was extracting the original from it but tar command gives following error:

```
 where numeric off_t value expected
```

**While gtar runs perfectly.**

Tar.gz was made using gtar command. I have other tar made with same process but they are fine.

Can anyone tell me what might be the cause of this. I have googled a little, but cannot find a satisfying answer.